# Bash script if .. else .. not working

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I'm new to the Bash scripting. I added the `if .. else` in the Bash script. My script is for making Docker-containers if the container doesn't exist, and creating a new container if it does exist. But the script never runs the `else` block; it always run the `if` block.

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash
tomcat=$(ssh michael@docker.example.com sudo docker ps -a | grep -w 'my-tomcat')
echo "$?"

if [ "$BRANCH" = "tomcat" ] && [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then
        ssh michael@docker.example.com /bin/sh <<-EOF
                { cd tomcat/ && sudo docker stop my-tomcat && sudo docker rm my-tomcat; } \
                && { sudo docker build -t tomcat .; } \
                && { sudo docker run -h tomcat --name my-tomcat -itd -p 2013:8080 tomcat; } \
                && { sudo docker start my-tomcat; }
        EOF
else
        ssh michael@docker.example.com /bin/sh <<-EOF
                { cd tomcat/ && sudo docker build -t tomcat .; } \
                && { sudo docker run -h tomcat --name my-tomcat -itd -p 2013:8080 tomcat; } \
                && { sudo docker start my-tomcat; } 
        EOF
fi
```

Comment: Is "$BRANCH" equals "tomcat" all the time?

Comment: Copy pasted your script in http://www.shellcheck.net/ and it threw an ugly error `When using <<-, you can only indent with tabs.` Fixing that error might help you solve the problem

Comment: Is "$BRANCH" equals "tomcat" all the time and what is the reason behind taking variable tomcat?

Comment: I would try assigning the $? to a variable (rc) before using it in the if and write `if [[ "$BRANCH" = "tomcat"  &&  "$rc" -eq 0 ]] ...` It may be that $? after the && is actually no longer referring to your original return code.

Comment: everybody thanks it's working now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you run:

```
echo "$?"

if [ "$BRANCH" = "tomcat" ] && [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then
```

In your `if` statement, `"$?"` will always be `0`, because it will represent the return value of `[ "$BRANCH" = "tomcat" ]`. And even if it didn't, it would represent the return value of the `echo`.

Do this instead to preserve the exit code:

```
tomcat="$(ssh michael@docker.example.com sudo docker ps -a | grep -w 'my-tomcat')"
tomcat_status="$?"

echo "$tomcat_status"

if [ "$BRANCH" = "tomcat" ] && [ "$tomcat_status" -eq 0 ]; then
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

```
[ .. ] && [ "$?" -eq 0 ]
#            ^ This will always be 0, since it's referring to the previous 
#              commands ([ .. ]) exit code
```

Store the exit code from earlier:

```
tomcat=$(ssh michael@docker.example.com sudo docker ps -a | grep -w 'my-tomcat')
tomcat_exit=$?
```

And what is `$BRANCH`? And `tomcat`?

```
if [ "$BRANCH" = "$tomcat" ] && [ "$tomcat_exit" -eq 0 ]; then
#                 ^ Is this a constant "tomcat" or variable "$tomcat"?
```

Comment: Oops, sorry, we worked on the same answer at the same time :)

Answer (score 1):

To aid debugging, type `set -x` before the `if`-statement, and `set +x` after the `fi` statement.

This enables execution tracing, and you can see the substitution for `$branch` and `$?!`.